# TypeError: canvas.getContext ('2d') is not a function

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, typeerror

I have written a simple jQuery code:

`canvas = $('#canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');`

And getting 'TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function' error. I have researched on here; while there are similar questions in which programmers have had similar issues, their context was different. I am also getting the following additional errors in the same line:

`at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)`

Here is my jQ code:

```
$(function () {
var arr_touches = [];
var canvas;
var ctx;
var down = false;
var color = 'black';
var width = 5;

canvas = $('#canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = width;
canvas.on({
    mousemove: function(e){
    xPos = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
    yPos = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;
   if(down == true)
     {
    ctx.lineTo(xPos,yPos); //create a line from old point to new one
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    }
}, 
mousedown:function(){
    down = true;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
}, 
mouseup:function(){
    down = false;
},
//handling mobile touch events
touchstart:function(evt){
    var touches = evt.changedTouches;
    for(var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) 
       {
           if(isValidTouch(touches[i])) 
              {
               evt.preventDefault();
               arr_touches.push(copyTouch(touches[i]));
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.fillStyle = color;
               ctx.fill();
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getContext()` is not a valid jquery method. It is a valid method on the HTML canvas element. Reference to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext).

I think what you're looking for is:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnadrh1d/1/)

Comment: happy to help :)